# Which component poped the ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a ContextMenuStrip and several DataGridView on a form and all of the grids are sharing the menu strip. Is it possible to figure out which grid caused the popup inside the click event of menu items?

Thanks 
Sam

Comment: You are asking for the ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl property.  Beware that it has a bug, only valid in the Opening event so be sure to subscribe that event and store the property value in a variable.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. Which "Opening event" are you referring to? I have been programming in C++ for almost 3 decades, but I'm new to C# and .net.

Comment: There is only one.  Be sure to use the MSDN library article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip?view=netframework-4.7.1#events-